# Manually rendered Django formset redirection problem at submition

Tags: python, django, redirect, formset

I have the following models defined:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    rfid_tag    = models.CharField()
    asset       = models.OneToOneField('Assets', default=None, null=True,
                                       on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT,)
    date        = models.DateTimeField(name='timestamp',                     
                                       auto_now_add=True,)
...

class Assets(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='Id', primary_key=True)
    assettag = models.CharField(db_column='AssetTag', unique=True, max_length=10)
    assettype = models.CharField(db_column='AssetType', max_length=150)
...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'Assets'
        ordering = ['assettag']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.assettag}"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return f"{self.assettag}"
```

For which I have created the following form and formset:

```
class ItemDeleteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    asset = forms.CharField(required=True,
                            help_text= "Item asset tag",
                            max_length=16,
                            label="AssetTag",
                            disabled=True,
                            )

    delete = forms.BooleanField(required=False,
                                label="Delete",
                                help_text='Check this box to delete the corresponding item',
                                )

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['asset']

ItemDeleteMultiple = forms.modelformset_factory(model=Item,
                                         form=ItemDeleteForm,
                                         extra=0,
                                         )
```

managed by the view:

```
class DeleteMultipleView(generic.FormView):
    template_name = '*some html file*'
    form_class = ItemDeleteMultiple
    success_url = reverse_lazy('*app_name:url_name*')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

And rendered in the template:

```
{% extends "pages/base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    <title>Delete Multiple</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Delete Multiple Items</h1>
<br>
    <form class="ManualForm" action ="." method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.management_form }}
        <table border="2">
            <tr><th colspan="3" scope="row">Select Items to Delete</th></tr>
            {% for item_form in form %}
            <tr>
                <td><label for="{{ item_form.asset.id_for_label }}">AssetTag {{forloop.counter}}:</label>
                    {% if item_form.non_field_errors %}
                        {{ item_form.non_field_errors }}
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if item_form.asset.errors %}
                        {{item_form.asset.errors}}
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
                <td>{{item_form.asset}}</td>
                <td>{{item_form.delete}}
                    {% if item_form.delete.errors %}
                        {{item_form.delete.errors}}
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <br>
        <input class = "btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Delete Selected" />
        <a href="{% url 'inventory:index' %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
    </form>

<form class="AutoForm" action ="." method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_table}}
    <input class = "btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Delete Selected" />
    <a href="{% url 'inventory:index' %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</a>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

When I submit AutoForm, everything is great. It takes me to `app_name:url_name`, but if I sumbit ManualForm I don't get redirected. It will simply clear all data and reload the form page with empty fields.

The HTTP POST response status code for AutoForm is 302, while for ManualForm is 200.

I don't understand how the template could influence the behavior of the url redirection. What am I doing wrong in the manual rendering of the formset?

Comment: pleas post your view for manual form

Comment: @bmons it's the same view. Both forms are in the same template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that adding:

```
{% for field in item_form.hidden_fields %}
    {{field}}
{% endfor %}
```

under `{% for item_form in form %}` will solve the issue.

I didn't understand very well from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-hidden-and-visible-fields):

> **Looping over hidden and visible fields**
>
> If you’re manually laying out a form in a template, as opposed to
>   relying on Django’s default form layout, you might want to treat
>   **< input type="hidden">** fields differently from non-hidden fields. For
>   example, because hidden fields don’t display anything, putting error
>   messages “next to” the field could cause confusion for your users – so
>   errors for those fields should be handled differently.

I just thought this is about errors, so I didn't care. But one of the first thing it says about forms is this:

> As an example, the login form for the Django admin contains several
>   < input> elements: one of type="text" for the username, one of
>   type="password" for the password, and one of type="submit" for the
>   “Log in” button. It also contains some hidden text fields that the
>   user doesn’t see, which Django uses to determine what to do next.
>
> It also tells the browser that the form data should be sent to the URL
>   specified in the < form>’s action attribute - /admin/ - and that it
>   should be sent using the HTTP mechanism specified by the method
>   attribute - post.

Maybe it will help someone else.